# Grant all permissions of a database to a user

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions, sql-grant

SQL Server: how to grant all permissions of a database to a user?

The user can create, drop, delete, insert, select, reference any objects (table, view, sequence, stored procedures, etc) in any schema of the database.

```
grant create, drop, delete, insert, select, reference on MyDatabase.* to user1
```

Comment: You could grant them the db_owner role in the database to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'user1';
```

When you are dealing with permissions you can refer the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-hierarchy-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) and [download](https://aka.ms/sql-permissions-poster) the poster sized chart of all Database Engine permissions in PDF format.

You can than search by role (for example `db_onwer`) and find what are the permissions that it has.